# Django Post request not receiving data

Tags: json, django, post

I've spent hours looking up this issue with no avail.

I am having issue with post data from an html page I am sending `{'username': 'username'}` but when I do request.POST.get('username') it returns none, I alos tried `{username, 'username'}`

```
def test_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.get('username'))
        return HttpResponse("Good!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Bad.")
```

Console Development Server

```
None <<<<

[12/Feb/2018 19:39:53] "POST /test_post HTTP/1.1" 200 5
(edited)
```

I am sending the data as `{'username': 'username'}`
That works correctly how come I am unable to get it to show up?

This is the Javascript code that calls from the page:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

   data = {username: username};
   console.log(data);
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open('POST', '/getuser', true);
   request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');
   request.send(data);
});
```

Comment: You reffer to it as `gitusername` in js and as `username` in django, aren't you?

Comment: Thats a mistake sorry they are both referred as username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the django view `test_post`, request.POST is a Query Dict (aka Dictionary).

When you use the method `.get(key)`, it looks for the `key` in the dictionary and returns you the value corresponding to the key.

In the `test_post` method, you have written `request.POST.get('username')` which means the string `'username'` as a key should be present in the `POST` dictionary.

---

When you do a POST using Javascript, and do `data = {username: username};` you are essentially making the key dynamic.

Eg. when you input "Bob" in username and click on submit, the variable `data`
will be `{'Bob': 'Bob'}`

Instead you should do:

```
 data = {'username': username}        //This ensures that the key remains same
```