# Django/DRF backend not receiving complete data from POST request

Tags: python, django, typescript, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to send data to my Django/DRF backend via Axios POST requests. Some of them have been working, but some of them haven't been. This snippet, for example, works fine:

```js
      axiosInstance.post(
        `/api/notes/`,
        {
          title,
          content: serialize(editorContent),
        }
      )
```

This one, however, has been causing problems:

```js
    axiosInstance.post(
      `/api/notebooks/`,
      {
        name: newNotebookName,
        user,
      }
    )
```

In the second snippet, the `name` attribute gets through to the backend, but for some reason the `user` attribute does not. I tried using `console.log` to see if `user` is undefined at the moment it's sent off to the backend and it isn't.

I tried to change the way I define the keys in the object I send to the backend so that they're not dynamic [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48759266/14397653) and the result hasn't changed.

The `user` variable is a string containing an email address, like `'foobar@gmail.com'`. I thought maybe Django blocked it by default for security reasons, but I split the string at the `@` and tried sending the first part only and it didn't work either.

I also tried defining a new variable so that the type of `user` is `string` rather than `string | undefined` and it still doesn't work. The value of `title` is also string and it gets through to the backend (it's defined in the `validated_data` object my serializer sees in its `create()` method). So I'm at a loss as to what this could be. Here are some of my files:

`axiosAPI.ts`

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/'

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    'xsrfHeaderName': 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    'xrsfCookieName': 'csrftoken',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token') ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') : null,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
  }
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config

    // Prevent infinite loops if login credentials invalid
    if (error.response.status === 406 && originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'auth/token/obtain') {
      window.location.href = '/login/'

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    // Respond to expired refresh tokens
    if (error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' && error.response.status === 401 && error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
      const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
      
      if (refreshToken) {
        const tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]))
        const currentTime = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)
        
        if (tokenObj.exp > currentTime) {
          return axiosInstance
            .post('/auth/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
            .then(response => {
              localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access)
              localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh)

              axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.access
              originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.access

              return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
              throw err;
            })
        } else {
          console.log('Refresh token is expired.')
          window.location.href = '/login/'
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Refresh token not available.')
        window.location.href = '/login/'
      }
    }
    
    // Respond to invalid access tokens
    if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
      const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
      
      return axiosInstance
        .post('/auth/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
        .then(response => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access)
          localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh)
          
          axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.access
          originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + response.data.access

          return axiosInstance(originalRequest)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          throw err;
        })
    }
  }
)
```

`notebooks/serializers.py`

```py
import bleach
import json

from rest_framework import serializers

from authentication.models import ErsatzNoteUser
from .models import Note, Notebook

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  note_id = serializers.SlugField(source='id', read_only=True, required=False)
  title = serializers.JSONField(required=False)
  content = serializers.CharField(required=False)
  notebook = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, required=False)

  date_modified = serializers.DateField(read_only=True, required=False)
  date_created = serializers.DateField(read_only=True, required=False)

  def create(self, validated_data):
    title = json.dumps(validated_data['title'])

    # Workaround to fix a currently unpatched bug in Slate
    # that occurs when an editor's contents begin with a list
    content = validated_data['content']
    if content.startswith('<ul') or content.startswith('<ol'):
      content = '<p></p>' + content

    response_data = {
      'title': title,
      'content': content,
    }

    return Note.objects.create(**response_data)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = json.dumps(validated_data['title'])

    # See the above comment in the 'create' method
    content = validated_data['content']
    if content.startswith('<ul') or content.startswith('<ol'):
      content = '<p></p>' + content
    
    instance.content = content

    instance.save()

    return instance

  class Meta:
    model = Note
    fields = [ 'note_id', 'title', 'content', 'notebook', 'date_modified', 'date_created' ]

class NotebookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  notebook_id = serializers.SlugField(source='id', read_only=True, required=False)
  name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64, default='')
  notes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

  def create(self, validated_data):
    # notebook_data = {
    #   'name': validated_data['name'],
    #   'user': ErsatzNoteUser.objects.get(email=validated_data['user']),
    # }
    print(validated_data)
    
    return Notebook.objects.create(name=validated_data['name'], user=ErsatzNoteUser.objects.get(email=validated_data['user']))
  
  class Meta:
    model = Notebook
    fields = [ 'notebook_id', 'name', 'notes', 'date_modified', 'date_created' ]
```

`notebooks/views.py`

```py
import json

from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import NoteSerializer, NotebookSerializer
from .models import Note, Notebook

class NoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = NoteSerializer
  
  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.notes.all()
  
  def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = NoteSerializer(instance)

    title = json.loads(serializer.data['title'])

    response_data = {
      'note_id': serializer.data['note_id'],
      'title': title,
      'content': serializer.data['content'],
      'notebook': serializer.data['notebook'],
      'date_modified': serializer.data['date_modified'],
      'date_created': serializer.data['date_created'],
    }

    return Response(response_data)

class NotebookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = NotebookSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.notebooks.all()
```

`notebooks/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from jsonfield import JSONField
from django.conf import settings

from .helpers import generate_slug

class Note(models.Model):
  """ Represents an individual note. """

  id = models.SlugField(max_length=settings.MAX_SLUG_LENGTH, primary_key=True)
  title = JSONField(null=True)
  content = models.TextField(null=True)
  notebook = models.ForeignKey('Notebook', related_name='notes', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='notes', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
  
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
      self.id = generate_slug(self, settings.MAX_SLUG_LENGTH)
    # Temporary expedients for the sake of development
    if not self.notebook:
      self.notebook = Notebook.objects.get(id='YyOzNhMFMPtN8HM')
    super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.id
  
  class Meta:
    ordering = [ '-date_modified', '-date_created', ]

class Notebook(models.Model):
  """ A collection of individual notes. """
  
  id = models.SlugField(max_length=settings.MAX_SLUG_LENGTH, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='')
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='notebooks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
      self.id = generate_slug(self, settings.MAX_SLUG_LENGTH)
    super(Notebook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
  
  class Meta:
    ordering = [ '-date_modified', '-date_created', 'name' ]
```

Please don't hesitate to ask if you'd like further info.

**EDIT:** Changed `NotebookViewSet` so that it has a `retrieve()` method, the result hasn't changed:

```py
class NotebookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = NotebookSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.notebooks.all()
  
  def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = NotebookSerializer(instance)

    response_data = {
      'name': serializer.data['name'],
      'user': serializer.data['user'],
    }

    return Response(response_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that under the hood, DRF considers `ForeignKey` fields to be `read_only`. Meaning it's solely to be used for representing the object, and shouldn't be part of any create or update process. According to the documentation:

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be included in the input during create or update operations. Any 'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer input will be ignored.

[Source.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

But this didn't matter to my database, which requires me to identify the user that corresponds to each new `Notebook` at the time of its creation, or else a NOT NULL constraint is violated. So I just overwrote the default `ModelViewSet` `create()` method to pass on the `user` string manually to my `NotebookSerializer` as part of `context`, allowing me to use it to get the corresponding user object in the database and assign it to the newly created `Notebook`. I went about it like this:

```py
class NotebookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = NotebookSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.notebooks.all()

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = NotebookSerializer(data=request.data, context={ 'request': request })
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

```py
class NotebookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  notebook_id = serializers.SlugField(source='id', read_only=True, required=False)
  name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64, default='')
  notes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

  def create(self, validated_data):
    return Notebook.objects.create(
      user=ErsatzNoteUser.objects.get(email=self.context['request'].user),
      **validated_data
    )
  
  class Meta:
    model = Notebook
    fields = [ 'notebook_id', 'name', 'notes', 'date_modified', 'date_created' ]
```

That's all it took.

Answer (score 0):

In your example your `NotebookViewSet` class does not have a `retrieve` method.

Comment: Changed my `NotebookViewSet` method so it has a `retrieve()` method like my `NoteViewSet`. Result hasn't changed. Edited the OP showing how I did it.

Comment: You might not need this tbh. My bad! Maybe try adding the `user` field to the  `NotebookSerializer`. I don't know what is the output of the debugging `print()` in your code, but you try to access `validated_data['user']` while not having that field in the Serializer.